# Set State from ajax call to insert into db outside function?

Tags: reactjs

```js
    async componentDidMount(){
        // Metrics
        await this.forumMetrics();
    }
```

I'm trying to insert data from an API that I'm calling from my ajax call. However, when I try to set state inside the function, it tells me that setstate is not a function. I looked this up and a lot of posts told me I had to `.bind(this)` which I did but it's still giving me the error.

Futhermore, I also ran into another problem of not being able to access the state from outside the function cause I need to insert it into my service worker that inserts the data into my db. I have access within the function but not outside which I need in order to bind the state to my model in my back-end.

Any suggestions? I feel like I'm close but missing something.

Here is my code:

```js
async forumMetrics(data){
    const getuserData = () => {
        $.getJSON({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'https://json.geoiplookup.io/api?callback=?',
            success: (data) => {
                //console.log(data);
                this.setState({
                    userIp: data.ip,
                    userCity: data.city,
                    userRegion: data.region,
                    userCountry: data.country_name,
                    userLatitude: data.latitude,
                    userLongitude: data.longitude
                })
                //console.log(this.state);
            },
        })
    }

    const result = getuserData();

    result;

    const metricData = {
        userIp: this.state.userIp,
        userCity: this.state.userCity,
        userCountry: this.state.userCountry,
        userRegion: this.state.userRegion,
        userLatitude: this.state.userLatitude,
        userLongitude: this.state.userLongitude,
        vieweddateTime: Moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'),
        createdDate: Moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'),
        year: Moment().format('YYYY'),
        month: Moment().format('MM')
    }

    const metricForum = await MetricService.insertpageView(metricData);

}
```

Comment: Could you please post in which part of your component you call that function (forumMetrics)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really not use jQuery to retrieve data. Use `fetch()` or `axios` or something like it.

That being said, your problem can be solved by using arrow functions. Instead of `function getuserData...`, try this:

```
    const getuserData = (result) => {
        $.getJSON({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'https://json.geoiplookup.io/api?callback=?',
            success: (data) => {
                console.log(data);
                // I have access to data in this function
                this.setState({
                    userIp: data.ip
                })
            },
        })
    }
```

Note that the `this` in the arrow functions is bound to the parent function's `this`.

Also, remember to bind your `forumMetrics` function on the component constructor.

EDIT:

I don't see you calling `getuserData()` anywhere...

EDIT 2:

You might want to make the `getUserData` a separate functionlike so:

```
async forumMetrics(data){
    const data = await this.getuserData();
    console.log(data);

    this.setState({
                userIp: data.ip,
                userCity: data.city,
                userRegion: data.region,
                userCountry: data.country_name,
                userLatitude: data.latitude,
                userLongitude: data.longitude
    });
}

getUserData(data) {
  return new Promise((accept, reject) => {
    $.getJSON({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'https://json.geoiplookup.io/api?callback=?',
      success: accept,
    }) 
  });
}
```

note that the `await` keyword inside an `async` function will wait for a promise to finish and use the accepted value to keep going.

You could simplify the `getUserData` function even more by just using `fetch`

```
getUserData() {
  return fetch('https://json.geoiplookup.io/api?callback=?');
}
```

Comment: So my problem was I wasn't using arrow functions instead of regular js functions?

Comment: That's an oversimplification. You could have used regular functions, but you'd need to have bound both of them. Note that you had a `function getuserData(result)` and a `function(data)` functions, and you were binding only the later one.

Comment: Okay. But how would I have access to that state from outside of the function? Right now I only have access to the state from within the `getuserData` function

Comment: Nevermind I got it, I had to simply move my service worker inside of the `getuserData` function and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Okay thank you for suggestions it looks like I still need more practice with async functions I'm going to study this a bit.

Answer (score 0):

#### forumMetrics() call

Your `forumMetrics` function isn't bound, so `this` is most likely undefined. You can either bind it in the constructor

```
constructor() {
  this.forumMetrics = this.forumMetrics.bind(this);
}
```

or declare it like:

```
forumMetrics = async () => {
}
```

The latter is experimental syntax though.

#### setState() call

If you go for the first option, inside the callback, your `this` is definitely not pointing to the class. If you're going to use jQuery for the ajax fetch, then capture the reference in a `self` variable (which is a bad practice, but so is using jQuery on React):

```
async forumMetrics(){
    const self = this;

    function getuserData(result) {
       ...
       self.setState({ ...stuff here... })
```